# How can I get the the fragment object in the current selected tab

Tags: android

I am using a Fragment tabs. each tab has a fragment in it in order to call it's reload method. how can I get the current selected fragment?

I need something like mTabHost.getFragment() but this method doesn't exist

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Latest"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(0));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Today"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Week"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Month"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(3));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator("Year"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(4));
```

How can I get the instance of MainFragment that the tab is using

I have tried this but i get a null pointer

```
MainFragment tag = (MainFragment)mTabHost.getTag();
        tag.reload();
```

Comment: in tab host there will settag and gettag , in settag you can set perticualr fregment and then get that perticular fregment

Comment: you can also assign tag in xml file and then get in java file

Comment: if u get selected tab then you can easily get which tab is selected and from you can get latest,month,year etc

Comment: mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()